# How to correct fragment declaration?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Fragment in my layout, but when typing the name of the class that android will open inside the fragment container, the error in the code line, but I'm declaring everything correctly, what could be wrong?

My code:

```
ConFragment newFragment = new ConFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.frameConteudo, newFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

My Exception:

```
C:\Users\Google\Desktop\Android\Fragment\app\src\main\java\com\example\fragment\Activity\MainActivity.java:28: error: no suitable method found for add(int,ConversasFragment)
    transaction.add(R.id.frameConteudo, newFragment);
               ^
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; ConversasFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your Fragment is of type Fragment (your `ConversasFragment` must extends `Fragment`)? And what kind of View is `R.id.frameConteudo`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that `transaction.add()`'s are incorrect. The parameters possible for `transaction.add()` are: `int, Fragment`, `Fragment, String`, `int, Fragment, String`, or `ViewGroup, Fragment, String`.  You gave the parameters `int, String`.

A fix for this would be to use:
`transaction.add((Fragment) findViewById(R.id.frameConteudo), newFragment);`

Hope this works!